# Running Curl and Grep on Windows

Tags: windows, grep, curl

I'm trying to run the following command in windows. I've managed to install cURL, but Grep still fails to identify as a command.

`curl -k --silent "http://192.168.1.135:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=getDevState&usr=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD" | grep -oP "(?<=motionDetectAlarm>).*?(?=</motionDetectAlarm>)"`

Is there an alternative command or a way to install Grep onto Windows?

**Update**
I've installed Grep and added the following to my Path variables, both system and user, and restarted to no avail.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32`

Comment: Have you installed grep? If so, make sure it is in your path. If you haven't installed it then go to [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

Comment: I used the installer from the site and left it to the default location (Program Files (x86)). Should I install in to the path (Windows/System32)?

Comment: Add the location to your path. See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](//superuser.com/q/284342)

Comment: I've done so yet I still receive the same error.

Comment: Did you start a new `cmd` shell after changing the path?

Comment: Yeah and it still provided that error even after a restart

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your complete path and the exact error message.

Comment: run `echo %PATH%`  and do `dir grep.exe /s/b`  by the way, the file should probably be in gnuwin32\bin  not in just gnuwin32.  And gnuwin32\bin should be in the path

Comment: anyhow gnuwin32's grep is probably old.. cygwin's is from 2017 `c:\cygwin\bin\grep.exe --version`  grep (GNU grep) 3.0   (When I last saw gnuwin32's grep it was quite a lot older, you can use it but it has some bugs and the later one is probably better anyway, and cygwin has the latest one). But worth getting the gnuwin32 one working  so you know how to do that as that is good knowledge for getting any command working.

Comment: Use cygwin as barlop said. Use the cygwin terminal and not the Windows terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> I've installed Grep and added the following to my Path variables, both system and user, and restarted to no avail.

A couple things to remember:

- As @barlop comments, the path should be e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`.
- It is perfectly fine to specify the whole path to `grep` e.g.:

  `curl -k --silent "http://192.168.1.135:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi?cmd=getDevState&usr=USERNAME&pwd=PASSWORD" | "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\grep.exe" -oP "(?<=motionDetectAlarm>).*?(?=</motionDetectAlarm>)"`